# How to improve the performance of this regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Consider the regular expression

```
^(?:\s*(?:[\%\#].*)?\n)*\s*function\s
```

It is intended to match Octave/MATLAB script files that start with a function definition.

However, the performance of this regular expression is incredibly slow, and I'm not entirely sure why.  For example, if I try evaluating it in Python,

```
>>> import re, time
>>> r = re.compile(r"^(?:\s*(?:[\%\#].*)?\n)*\s*function\s")
>>> t0=time.time(); r.match("\n"*15); print(time.time()-t0)
0.0178489685059
>>> t0=time.time(); r.match("\n"*20); print(time.time()-t0)
0.532235860825
>>> t0=time.time(); r.match("\n"*25); print(time.time()-t0)
17.1298530102
```

In English, that last line is saying that my regular expression takes 17 seconds to evaluate on a simple string containing 25 newline characters!

What is it about my regex that is making it so slow, and what could I do to fix it?

---

**EDIT:** To clarify, I would like my regex to match the following string containing comments:

```
# Hello world
function abc
```

including any amount of whitespace, but not

```
x = 10
function abc
```

because then the string does not start with "function".  Note that comments can start with either "%" or with "#".

Comment: Please mention your sample string

Comment: Just using `re.match(r"\s*function\s", s)` is enough to solve the issue if you plan to match [such text](https://regex101.com/r/pC1uJ1/3). You have a case of classical catastrophic backtracking with your regex that has nested quantifiers with subpatterns that may match one another.

Comment: I added more detail to the question with regard to the types of strings that the regex should and shouldn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `\s` with `[\t\f ]` so they don't catch newlines. This should only be done by the whole non-capturing group `(?:[\t\f ]*(?:[\%\#].*)?\n)`.
The problem is that you have three greedy consumers that all match `'\n'` (`\s*`, `(...\n)*` and again `\s*`).
In your last timing example, they will try out all strings `a`, `b` and `c` (one for each consumer) that make up `25*'\n'` or any substring `d` it begins with, say `e` is what is ignored, then `d+e == 25*'\n'`.
Now find all combinations of `a`, `b`, `c` and `e` so that `a+b+c+e == d+e == 25*'\n'` considering also the empty string for one or more variables. It's too late for me to do the maths right now but I bet the number is huge :D

By the way [regex101](https://regex101.com) is a great site to try out regular expressions. They automatically break up expressions and explain their parts and they even provide a debugger.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense and the change improves the performance of the regex while still matching the same set of strings.

Answer (score 0):

To speedup you can use this regex:

```
p = re.compile(r"^\s*function\s", re.MULTILINE)
```

Since you're not actually capturing lines starting with `#` or `%` anyway, you can use `MULTILINE` mode and start matching from the same line where `function` keyword is found.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it matches strings that contain "function" at the beginning of any line in the body, not just at the top and potentially after lines with comments.

Comment: So you only want `function` to match after comments? What if `function` is the first line?

Comment: It's okay if there is nothing before "function" (first line) or if it's only whitespace that appears before "function".  I added more detail to the question.

Comment: So an empty line before `function` is also okay?